# Why is my VNC cursor just a dot?

Tags: windows-7, macos, vnc

I am using [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/index.html) to connect from my Windows 7 x64 machine to Mac OSX running Vine Server.

The cursor I see on the Mac desktop is just a dot rather than a normal cursor. What setting have I missed that will give a familiar arrow cursor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VNC Viewer connection options, under mouse and keyboard settings, check the radio button for "Track remote cursor locally". It sounds like you have it set on "Don't show remote cursor".

Comment: In version 1.1 from a Windows client to Linux server, this does not resolve the small dot cursor issue.  The -normalcursor option below is a contemporary solution.

Answer (score 11):

When Launching UltraVNC use the command line argument "-normalcursor" to use the windows arrow.

Example: "vncviewer.exe -normalcursor"

Comment: Best answer for local cursor (not the remote one). This is the same as using `localcursor=2` in *.VNC configuration file BTW.

Comment: This works best for me.

Comment: this is the best response

Answer (score 10):

I want to add some insights about Windows 10 VNC viewing. If you have trouble seeing a mouse cursor on a Windows 10 machine with no mouse attached, you can enable the "mouse control using Numpad keys" feature:

1. Open start menu.
2. Click the "Settings" cog
3. Click the "Ease of Access" menu item
4. Select "Mouse" in the left pane
5. Enable "Use numeric pad to move mouse around the screen"

This forces Windows to show a mouse cursor even with no physical mouse attached thus making your VNC life much easier. Bonus: you can actually see "Resize window" cursors on the windows edges!

Comment: This worked for me, thanks so much! My VNC viewer would always use its' own standard arrow pointer, which mean I could never tell what the actual Windows 10 cursor was showing, particularly annoying when trying to resize windows! Now it shows the correct pointer :)

Comment: The second I read this it all made sense as to why I only had a dot when remoting into my server (which has no monitor, no mouse, no keyboard). So I dug around for a mouse I don't need and hooked it in the back. Problem fixed, just a different way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When using *.vnc-Files to save connections, you can edit the file and change/add the line:

```
localcursor=2
```

to show a normal local cursor for that connection.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with UltraVNC, so I tried TightVNC. TightVNC has an option to change the local cursor shape to an arrow from the small circle/dot. I could not find that option in UltraVNC. That is the only option I changed from the defaults. Remote server was Ubuntu and the client was Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been driving nuts for years.  I tried all the suggestions I could find.  Nothing worked.  HOWEVER i just figured out that if I enable mouse pointer trails on the the windows machine i get a usable cursor!!!!!!!!!

Comment: btw, i would have put this on the realvnc support page BUT i could never succesfully log in there to make a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse and keyboard not working in VNC viewer ?

To resolve the issue follow below process
In option tab of VNC viewer settings
Uncheck *view only (inputs ignored)*

Then apply the settings

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In VNC Viewer connection options, under mouse and keyboard settings, check the radio button for "Track remote cursor locally". It sounds like you have it set on "Don't show remote cursor"

to add on this answer from John T, what worked for me is setting both:
DotWhenNotCursor, and UseLocalCursor to False (apply) and then back to True.
only then the mouse returned to work on my VNC.

Answer (score -1):

I too experienced a similar problem using Windows 7 and the RealVNC (R6652).  However, I was able to resolve it by resetting the display of the Operating System configuration back to its original default value.  Specifically, clicked control panel - display and selected the default radio button of 100%.  Afterward, the  cursor arrow re-appeared properly on the remote server side of the display window.